# List contacts closest to me with sql query

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I want to sort the list of people who are close to the logged in user with the following sql query. But I want to add a constraint to the query. ***What do I have to do if I want to list people within 10 kilometers.***

```
SELECT *,((((acos(sin((".$latitude."*pi()/180)) * 
sin((`ulat`*pi()/180))+ 
cos((".$latitude."*pi()/180)) * 
cos((`ulat`*pi()/180)) * 
cos(((".$longitude."- `ulong`)*
pi()/180))))*180/pi())*60*1.1515*1.609344)) 
AS `distance` FROM users 
WHERE ulat IS NOT NULL AND 
ulong IS NOT NULL AND 
user_status = '1' AND user_id <> $userid ORDER BY `distance` ASC
```

Comment: `HAVING distance < 10`

Comment: @Barmar where should i but it ?

Comment: Where does the documentation of `SELECT` syntax say to put it?

Comment: You sure about that formula? That's not haversine. You also should bind values.. but this really is just a mysql question.

Comment: @Barmar If i use `HAVING distance < 10 ` like this : `FROM dot_users HAVING distance < '$distance' WHERE ulat` then i get this error: `You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE ulat IS NOT NULL AND ulong IS NOT NULL AND user_status = '1' AND user_id <' at line 1`

Comment: I guess you didn't read the documentation carefully.  The order of clauses in `SELECT` is `SELECT ... FROM ... JOIN ... WHERE ... GROUP BY ... HAVING ... ORDER BY ...`

Comment: See [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_syntax)

Comment: @Barmar I failed to write this query. Can you help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

Order by distance :

```
SELECT *, distance ((((acos(sin((".$latitude."*pi()/180)) * 
sin((`ulat`*pi()/180))+ 
cos((".$latitude."*pi()/180)) * 
cos((`ulat`*pi()/180)) * 
cos(((".$longitude."- `ulong`)*
pi()/180))))*180/pi())*60*1.1515*1.609344)) 
AS `distance` FROM users 
WHERE ulat IS NOT NULL AND 
ulong IS NOT NULL AND 
user_status = 1 AND user_id <> $userid AND distance < 10 ORDER BY distance ASC
```

Comment: No, it's still on the list of people who are 700 kilometers away.

Comment: still tryed, got: `Unknown column 'distance' in 'where clause'`

Comment: I know you are updated the answer. I have tested your updated answer it gives me `Unknown column 'distance' in 'where clause'`

Comment: `Incorrect parameter count in the call to native function 'distance'`

Answer (score 0):

Use `HAVING` to filter the results.

```
SELECT *,((((acos(sin((".$latitude."*pi()/180)) * 
sin((`ulat`*pi()/180))+ 
cos((".$latitude."*pi()/180)) * 
cos((`ulat`*pi()/180)) * 
cos(((".$longitude."- `ulong`)*
pi()/180))))*180/pi())*60*1.1515*1.609344)) 
AS `distance` FROM users 
WHERE ulat IS NOT NULL AND 
ulong IS NOT NULL AND 
user_status = '1' AND user_id <> $userid 
HAVING DISTANCE < 10
ORDER BY `distance` ASC
```